# google captcha displayed distorted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, accordion, captcha

I have a contact-us form with Google captcha inside a JQuery accordion section and the recaptcha is displayed distorted. I suspect some JS conflict to be the reason but not sure.
Does anyone have any idea?

I cannot post images yet, you can see it at http://trcont-ekb.ru/contacts.php

Here's the code:

```
<form action="sendmessage.php" method="POST">
            <fieldset>              
                <table style="border:none; border-spacing: 0px; padding:0px; width:450px; font-size:14px; font-family:calibri,sans-serif;">
                <tr>                
                <td height="30" style="text-align:right; vertical-align:top;"><label for="name">Имя:*</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" required name="name" size="30" /></td></tr><br />                    
                <tr><td height="30" style="text-align:right; vertical-align:top;"><label for="phone">Телефон:*</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" required name="phone" size="30" /></td></tr><br />
                <tr><td height="30" style="text-align:right; vertical-align:top;"><label for="email">Ваш e-mail:*</label></td>
                <td><input type="email" required name="email" size="30" /></td></tr><br />
                <tr><td height="30" style="text-align:right; vertical-align:top;"><label for="where">Выберите адресата:*</label></td>
                <td><select style="width:237px; height:24px;" required name="where" >
                    <option value="">---------</option>
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value=""></option>
                </select></td></tr><br />
                <tr><td height="30" style="text-align:right; vertical-align:top;"><label for="messsage">Ваше сообщение:*</label></td>
                            <td><textarea rows="10" cols="30" required name="message" id="message"></textarea></td></tr></table><br />
                            <div align="center">
                            <div id="captcha">
                            <?php
                            require_once('recaptchalib.php');
                $publickey = "123456789";
                echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
                ?>
                </div>
                </div>
                <br /><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправить сообщение" id="submit" /><br />
            </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Does it look something like [this](http://i.imgur.com/wJja6QV.png)?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `tr { height: 2em; }` or override it with `height: auto` for table rows within `#captcha`.

Comment: Thank you! This helped!:) Maybe you know why the map opens in the same accordion with position marker outside the shown area?